# How to set three different textsize in single textview in android

Tags: android, html, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I want to set the three different text size in single textview as like the below image sample,[image]

I have tried with Html as like the below,

```
 StringBuilder fontString = new StringBuilder();

    fontString.append("<small>");
    fontString.append("1.78");
    fontString.append("</small>");      
    fontString.append("<big><b>");
    fontString.append("33");
    fontString.append("</b></big>");        
    fontString.append("<sup>");
    fontString.append("<small>");
    fontString .append("2");
    fontString.append("</small>");
    fontString.append("</sup>");
```

Also I tried SpannableString formatting,

```
SpannableString  spanString = new SpannableString("1.34456");
    spanString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.75f), 0,spanString.length()-2-1, 0);
    spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), spanString.length()-2-1, spanString.length()-1, 0);
    spanString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), spanString.length()-2-1,  spanString.length()-1, 0);     
    spanString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(3f), spanString.length()-2-1, spanString.length()-1, 0);        
    spanString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.25f), spanString.length()-1, spanString.length(), 0);
```

like the below mentioned image,
[image]

Please suggest me if you know the solution,I have tried with superscript or subscript also but no luck.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use three different TextViews, each with different TextSize ?

Comment: try with `android:gravity="top"`

Comment: No i have to implement in single Textview to maintain the standard in the code @Marcus

Comment: I tried with gravity @Froyo but it didn't help me to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the solution,

Use this class to align the Text,

```
  import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.MetricAffectingSpan;

public class SuperscriptSpanAdjuster extends MetricAffectingSpan {
    double ratio = 0.5;

    public SuperscriptSpanAdjuster() {
    }

    public SuperscriptSpanAdjuster(double ratio) {
        this.ratio = ratio;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint paint) {
        paint.baselineShift += (int) (paint.ascent() * ratio);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
        paint.baselineShift += (int) (paint.ascent() * ratio);
    }

}
```

Here, you can find the SpannedString format,

```
SpannableString  spanString = new SpannableString(value);
    /* To show the text in top aligned(Normal)*/
    spanString.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpanAdjuster(0.7), 0,spanString.length()-mostSignificantLength-leastSignificantLength, SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    /* Show the number of characters is normal size (Normal)*/
    spanString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.3f), 0,spanString.length()-mostSignificantLength-leastSignificantLength, 0);
    /*To set the text style as bold(MostSignificant)*/
    spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), spanString.length()-mostSignificantLength-leastSignificantLength, spanString.length()-leastSignificantLength, 0);
    /*To set the text color as WHITE(MostSignificant)*/
    spanString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), spanString.length()-mostSignificantLength-leastSignificantLength,  spanString.length()-leastSignificantLength, 0);
    /*Show the number of characters as most significant value(MostSignificant)*/
    spanString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2.3f), spanString.length()-mostSignificantLength-leastSignificantLength, spanString.length()-leastSignificantLength, 0);

    /* To show the text in top aligned(LestSignificant)*/
    spanString.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpanAdjuster(1.2), spanString.length()-leastSignificantLength, spanString.length(), SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    /*To set the text style as bold(LestSignificant)*/
    spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), spanString.length()-leastSignificantLength, spanString.length(), 0);
    /*Show the number of characters as most significant value(LestSignificant)*/
    spanString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.8f), spanString.length()-leastSignificantLength, spanString.length(), 0);
```

Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Html tags such as

```
<h1>...<h6>
```

using below code

```
txtview.setText(Html.fromHtml("your text here with HTML heading tags");
```

May this help you

Comment: each header tag moves the next line @Kat-hat. Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) with [RelativeSizeSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/RelativeSizeSpan.html) to create multiple text sizes in one textview. Set the gravity of the text to TOP so text will attached to the top edge.

Answer (score 0):

you use method `Html.fromhtml("your html formatted text")` It worked for me, thanks.