# Set different text size in Android TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have one TextView with only 1 line of text. Now I have to put an extra line to set the state of the user. So I set the property `android:lines="2"`

the textview looks like:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/providerName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:lines="2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

The way I add the text is like:

```
mNameAndStatus.setText(providerNameText +  "\n" + mUserStatus);
```

Image how is actually.

[image]

The problem is that the first lines must me in *Large* text, but the second line must be *medium* or *small* and I don't know if is it possible.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30097454/2987421

Comment: It would really be better to just use a second `TextView` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
String asHtml = firstLine+"<br/><small>"+secondLine+"</small>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(asHtml));
```

or simply use [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) ([AbsoluteSizeSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/AbsoluteSizeSpan.html))

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this :

```
mNameAndStatus.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 24);
```

where your text size is given in sp (24sp in the example).

Here are all `TypedValue`s http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html